# Fedora login loop

Tags: fedora, login

After updating fedora and reboot the system keeps looping on the login menu.

I can’t get into other users neither and I can’t access the tty with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. At this point I’m really lost and I don’t have any more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

At the GRUB2 prompt during boot, choose to edit the boot entry and add

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

...to the kernel line.

This will make it boot into the text login prompt, where you can do more debugging.

Comment: Is this the same as just adding `3`?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how long it’ll be that way

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a few times, and it's universally been something wrong with the user's home directory:

- Out of disk space (or NFS quota)
- Not mounted at all
- Read-only

If you just installed updates, and you don't have a separate /home partition, my money would be on out of disk space.